# Type hint a subclass of list

Tags: python, python-3.x

I use a class which subclasses the built-in list.

```
class Qry(list):
    """Stores a list indexable by attributes."""

    def filter(self, **kwargs):
        """Returns the items in Qry that has matching attributes.

        Example:
            obj.filter(portfolio='123', account='ABC').
        """

        values = tuple(kwargs.values())

        def is_match(item):
            if tuple(getattr(item, y) for y in kwargs.keys()) == values:
                return True
            else:
                return False

        result = Qry([x for x in self if is_match(x)], keys=self._keys)

        return result
```

Now I want to type hint:

```
class C:
    a = 1

def foo(qry: Qry[C]):
    """Do stuff here."""
```

How do you type hint a custom container class in python 3.5+?

Comment: Can't you do `def foo(qry: Qry):`?

Comment: You are right, there was a typo. I meant to create a Qry (list) of another type of object. See the edit.

Comment: I don't think you can do this easily. You can do `from typing import TypeVar, List; T = TypeVar('T'); class MyList(List[T]):...` (note the upper case) but AFAIK you can't enforce the generic constraint on e.g. append unless you override every method to add the annotation for the generic type T.

Comment: @JaredSmith Please post your comment as the answer. It's correct.

Comment: @S.Lott done and thank you.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this rather easily:

```
from typing import TypeVar, List
T = TypeVar('T')
class MyList(List[T]): # note the upper case
    pass
```

Comment: Untrue mate, using `TypeVar` does enforce the constraint down the line. That's somewhat the point of Generics...

Comment: This does not yet work as intended (at least in PyCharm. In the `foo()` function, typing `qry.filter(a=1)[0].` does not bring up the attribute `a` as intended.

Comment: This can at least be used to produce Sphinx documentation just fine!